# How do you insert a row and preserve a column of formulas on a separate tab?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Let's say I have a Google spreadsheet with a Data sheet and Previews sheet in it.

Previews has one column, and it's a complex concatenate formula that builds text from a template using the fields from the appropriate row in Data. The formula is copied down the column and corresponds correctly to the right rows on the Data sheet. So for each row of Data, a row in Preview is generated.

So far so good.

But if I insert a new row in Data, the formulas in Previews shift down by one row where the inserted row in Data starts.

IE, if I insert a row above 3 in Data (making 3 become 4), the rows in Previews,

```
=Concatenate(Data!A1, Data!B1, Data!C1)
=Concatenate(Data!A2, Data!B2, Data!C2)
=Concatenate(Data!A3, Data!B3, Data!C3)
```

Become,

```
=Concatenate(Data!A1, Data!B1, Data!C1)
=Concatenate(Data!A2, Data!B2, Data!C2)
=Concatenate(Data!A4, Data!B4, Data!C4)
```

(There's more to this, such as whitespace in strings and absolute references to template cells in a template sheet. But this is basically what's happening.)

If I make the formula absolute, then it can't be copied down. But if it can be copied down, it shifts when new rows get inserted in Data.

I can fix it with an installable trigger (by inserting a corresponding row in Previews and copying the formula to it.) But I'd like to know if it's possible just with formulas.

I'm a freelancer setting this sheet up for a client, so it has to be automatic without having to teach them things.

Comment: You can record a Google Sheets Macro to help automate the task without changing the formulas. Otherwise, you'll need to use arrayformulas that reference the entire column, e.g. `A1:A` instead of `A1:A100` Arrayformulas won't work for all operations (i.e. those that naturally take a range/multiple input, such as `MAX()` or `MIN()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using array formulas. Those eliminate the need to drag down and won't cause issues when new rows are inserted.

```
=Arrayformula(Data!A1:A&Data!B1:B&Data!C1:C)
```

(Change range to suit)

Comment: It doesn't seem to work.

The original formula is

`=IF(OR(ISBLANK(Data!F1), ISBLANK(Data!E1), ISBLANK(Data!H1), ISBLANK(Data!B1)), , CONCATENATE(IF(REGEXMATCH(LEFT(Data!F1, 1), "[aAeEiIoOuU]"), TemplateData!$B$1, TemplateData!$A$1), " ", Data!F1, " ", TemplateData!$A$2, " ", Data!E1, " ", TemplateData!$A$3,CHAR(10), CHAR(10),Data!H1, CHAR(10), CHAR(10), TemplateData!$A$4, Data!B1, CHAR(10), CHAR(10), IF(ISBLANK(Data!G1), , CONCATENATE(TemplateData!$A$5, " ", Data!G1, CHAR(10), CHAR(10))), TemplateData!$A$6, Data!B1, CHAR(10), CHAR(10), TemplateData!$A$7))`

But that IF becomes false.